# Sqlite database couldnt found when run in the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my application i m using sqlite database.when i run it in iphone simulater it works fine.but it cant connect database with device.the path for that database is:

```
 /Users/taxsmart7/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/A644750D- 5175-4FF1-BDA7-6EDF65895180/Documents/BillSplitter.sqlite
```

when i connect with my device the database display blank.

Comment: are you bundling a pre-prepared .sqlite file with the app, or is the app creating a fresh db?

Comment: yup i am using pre-prepaid sqlite file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only read sqlite3 database it makes sense to work with database in app bundle.
You open database as in example:

```
NSString *pathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameOfYourDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite3"]; // extension could not be .sqlite3!!! Have a look on your db file.
sqlite3 *database;
int res = sqlite3_open_v2([pathname UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, NULL);
if (res != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Error opening database %@", pathname);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

If you need to write in database on first run of your app you need to copy database file from app bundle into app documents directory and then open database for read and write access.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal, this is the path of the database when running on simulator, saying differently : on your mac. The path to your application, and the whole "file system" hierarchy when running on device is totally different.
You shouldn't use any absolute path in your application, and work only from the application root folder, which is something like :
`/private/var/mobile/Applications/A644750D-5175-4FF1-BDA7-6EDF65895180/`

So if you wanna use a database in your application, you'll have to copy it in the bundle and find the right path to it, or to create one when excuting on device.

HTH

**EDIT** : the path scheme above may be wrong, I suspect it's just the path to the "Documents" folder reserved to the application. Anyway, my advice stays the same : use relative pathes.

Comment: How can I set this this path?

Comment: You don't have to, you have to use a relative path. Have a look on your bundle structure, and just use something like `./Data/mydb.sqlite`.

Comment: where to give the relative path?

Comment: In addition, knowing you use a pre-prepared file, think about checking bundle options like "copy to output folder" or something like that (can't be more precise since I use MonoTouch only, sorry), otherwise you could set the right path but no result because the file wouldn't be present on device.

Comment: You have to use this relative path when opening your DB connection. I think you use some string like `Data Source=/path/to/DB.sqlite`, no? Here is the path to be replaced.